# Condition in GROUP_CONCAT selection

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I have 3 tables and I'm joining them to get some data.

```
-----------------
Table Name: users
-------------------------------
|user_id  | user_name |
-------------------------------
123      | abc
-------------------------------
223      | bcd
-------------------------------
323      | cde
-------------------------------

-----------------
Table Name: limit
-------------------------------
user_id  | limit_id
-------------------------------
123      | 1
-------------------------------
223      | 2
-------------------------------
323      | 3
-------------------------------
323      | 4
-------------------------------

-------------------------
Table Name: limit_setting
-------------------------------
limit_id | date_limit
-------------------------------
1        | 2016-09-29 12:00:00
-------------------------------
2        | 2016-09-28 12:00:00
-------------------------------
3        | 2016-09-27 12:00:00
-------------------------------
1        | 2016-09-27 12:00:00
-------------------------------
1        | 2016-09-24 12:00:00
-------------------------------
4        | 2016-09-25 12:00:00
-------------------------------
4        | 2016-09-26 12:00:00
-------------------------------
```

I need to get a result like this. I am stuck with the GROUP_CONCAT for the dates column. 
The date column should have all entries other than the MAX date. If there is only one entry in the `limit_setting` table for that limit_id then it shouldn't show anything for that user. 
`count_dates` : its the number of entries which are there in the `limit_setting` table.

```
Desired output

----------------------------------------------------------------------
user_name | dates                                       | count_dates   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
abc       | 2016-09-27 12:00:00 , 2016-09-24 12:00:00   | 3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
bcd       |                                             | 1 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
cde       |                                             | 1 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
cde       | 2016-09-26 12:00:00                         | 2 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
SELECT PP.`user_name`, count(ESL.Limit_id) as count_dates,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ESL.date_limit SEPARATOR ',') as dates 
FROM users as PP INNER JOIN `limit` as PAL ON PP.Id = PAL.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN limit_setting as ESL ON ESL.LimitId = PAL.limitId 
GROUP BY PAL.limitId
```

Additionally i tried with (which returned nothing)

```
SELECT ESL.date_limit, MAX(date_limit) as max_date, PP.`user_name`, count(ESL.Limit_id) as count_dates, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(ESL.date_limit SEPARATOR ',') as dates 
FROM users as PP INNER JOIN `limit` as PAL ON PP.Id = PAL.PlayerId 
LEFT JOIN limit_setting as ESL ON ESL.LimitId = PAL.limitId 
GROUP BY PAL.limitId
HAVING ESL.date_limit > max_date
```

I tried with `Find_in_set` but not sure how to use it effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_name,        
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(date_limit ORDER BY date_limit), 
                                 ',', COUNT(*) - 1) 
            ELSE ''
       END AS dates,             
       COUNT(*) AS count_dates
FROM users as PP 
INNER JOIN `limit` as PAL ON PP.user_id = PAL.user_id
LEFT JOIN limit_setting as ESL ON ESL.limit_id = PAL.limit_id
GROUP BY user_name
```

The query uses [**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function in order to get all dates returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` *except from* the last date. Using `ORDER BY` inside `GROUP_CONCAT` we can place the maximum date at the end, so that `SUBSTRING_INDEX` truncates exactly this date.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b616a/2)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and also for the explanation... I never used `SUBSTRING_INDEX` before and had no idea about it... thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a subquery to return the max date per limit and join this back to the limit setting table to eliminate the maximum dates from the `group_concat()` with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT 
    PP.`user_name`,
    count(ESL.Limit_id) as count_dates,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE
                     WHEN ESL.date_limit<>ls.maxdate THEN ESL.date_limit
                     ELSE ''
                 END SEPARATOR ',') as dates 
FROM users as PP
INNER JOIN `limit` as PAL ON PP.Id = PAL.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN limit_setting as ESL ON ESL.LimitId = PAL.limitId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT LimitId, MAX(date_limit) as maxdate
           FROM limit_setting
           GROUP BY LimitId
          ) ls ON ESL.LimitId=ls.LimitId
GROUP BY PP.`user_name`
```

Comment: I got the result with this as well but with a ',' in the beginning of the `dates` field... like this : `,2016-09-23 00:00:00,2016-09-21 00:00:00,2016-09-2..`